# How to determine error bars given number of flips

Tags: error

I have a biased coin; it's going to return either heads or tails at some percentage.  If I run a test and get back say 28 heads out of 40 flips, how can i best add error bars to indicate i don't have a lot of samples, and the real results could be higher or lower?

Comment: look, i am a total nube at statistics, I know enough to know this is very basic and i apologize in advance if it's too basic for this site.

Comment: Are you after something like a (binomial) [confidence interval for a proportion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval)? Or do you want error bars that represent something else?

Comment: Although this question is asked and answered at http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/4756, the language is technical and the answer is incomplete (from the point of view of someone without a statistical background). More elementary expositions of the same ideas are found at http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/3402.  The theory behind all this is explained (in very elementary terms but in great detail) at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/18609.

Comment: @Glen_b yes, i think that's what i'm after.  The elementary explanations at related questions were helpful.